# Proving self-injectivity of a finite dimensional Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, alternative-proof, noncommutative-algebra

Due to a theorem of Nakayama, a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $\mathbb{k}$ is self-injective provided that each simple right module of $A$ is the socle of a projective indecomposable right module of $A$ (the converse holds as well). The only proof I am aware of argues with Morita Theory. I wonder if there is a more direct approach.

Here is a sketch of the proof in the book of Skowroński and Yamagata:

> Let $e_1, \dots, e_n \in A$ be a complete set of mutually orthogonal and non-isomorphic primitive idempotents. Each simple right module of $A$ occurs exactly once as the top of some $e_iA$, and by the assumption above, each occurs exactly once as the socle of some $e_jA$. Hence, there is a “Nakayama permutation” $\pi \in S_n$ such that $\mathrm{top}(e_{\pi(i)}A) \cong \mathrm{soc}(e_iA)$. Now $e_iA$ embeds into the injective hull of $\mathrm{soc}(e_iA)$, which is $D(Ae_{\pi(i)})$, where $D = \mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{k}(-,\mathbb{k})$ is the usual duality. By setting $e = e_1 + \dots + e_n$, we get a monomorphism $\varphi \colon eA \hookrightarrow D(Ae)$.
>
> At this point the authors argue that $\varphi$ induces a monomorphism $eAe \hookrightarrow D(eAe)$ of right $eAe$-modules which must be an isomorphism by comparing dimensions. So $eAe$ is a Frobenius algebra, and $A$ must be self-injective being Morita equivalent to $eAe$.

Can we come to the conclusion more directly by showing that $\varphi \colon eA \hookrightarrow D(Ae)$ must already be an isomorphism? Of course it suffices to show that $eA$ (the minimal projective generator of right $A$-modules) and $Ae$ (the minimal projective generator of left $A$-modules) have the same dimension.

Comment: I'm not sure, but Morita theory is probably not available to Nakayama when he proved; so the original proof is likely to be (seemingly) free from Morita theory.

Comment: @Orat You are right. According to the authors the statement was proven by Nakayama in 1941 in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968984). Morita equivalence was invented in 1958. However, at first sight I do not find the statement in that paper...

Comment: As far as I understand (the paper is hard to read for me), Nakayama proves several conditions for Artinian rings to be equivalent, which characterize quasi Frobenius rings. I think that under the above hypotheses, Nakayama's paper contains a proof that the lattice of left ideals of $A$ is isomorphic to the lattice of right ideals of $A$ in a specific way. This in turn implies (by a theorem which can be found in Lam's book) that $A$ is self-injective. However, this proof would be quite complicated. I hope the above argument can be completed in an easier way.